# Insertion in AVL Tree

Tags: python, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I implemented an AVL Tree in Python, wherein I am inserting the nodes recursively. However, when I am inserting plenty of nodes (around 500000 nodes), there is an error message which says 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison.' If the recursion in Python cannot be done so deeply, then is there any way that I can manage to insert around 1,000,000 nodes in my tree?
Here is my insertion code:

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = val
        self.leftChild = None
        self.rightChild = None
        self.parent = None
        self.balanceFactor = 0

    def setParent(self, pt):
        self.parent = pt

    def insert(self, data):
        if self.value == data:
            return False
        elif self.value > data:
            if self.leftChild:
                return self.leftChild.insert(data)
            else:
                self.leftChild = Node(data)
                self.leftChild.setParent(self)
                self.updateBalance(self.leftChild)
        else:
            if self.rightChild:
                return self.rightChild.insert(data)
            else:
                self.rightChild = Node(data)
                self.rightChild.setParent(self)
                self.updateBalance(self.rightChild)
```

And here is the separate code to act as UI for the user which is put in another class:

```
class Tree(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insert(self, data):
        if self.root:
            return self.root.insert(data)
        else:
            self.root = Node(data)
```

I just realized that it is working fine when I am just keeping it as simply Binary Search Tree. However, when I am putting the code to convert it into AVL Tree, it is showing that error.

EDIT: if anyone is interested in seeing my full AVL Tree code, then here it is:

```
def isLeftChild(self):
    return self.parent and self.parent.leftChild == self

def isRightChild(self):
    return self.parent and self.parent.rightChild == self

def isRoot(self):
    return not self.parent




def updateBalance(self, node):
    if node.balanceFactor > 1 or node.balanceFactor < -1:
        self.rebalance(node)
        return
    if node.parent != None:
        if node.isLeftChild():
            node.parent.balanceFactor += 1
        elif node.isRightChild():
            node.parent.balanceFactor -= 1

        if node.parent.balanceFactor != 0:
            self.updateBalance(node.parent)

def rebalance(self, node):
    if node.balanceFactor < 0:
        if node.rightChild:
            if node.rightChild.balanceFactor > 0:
                self.rotateRight(node.rightChild)
                self.rotateLeft(node)
            else:
                self.rotateLeft(node)
    elif node.balanceFactor > 0:
        if node.leftChild:
            if node.leftChild.balanceFactor < 0:
                self.rotateLeft(node.leftChild)
                self.rotateRight(node)
            else:
                self.rotateRight(node)

def rotateRight(self, rotRoot):
    newRoot = rotRoot.leftChild
    rotRoot.leftChild = newRoot.rightChild
    if newRoot.rightChild != None:
        newRoot.rightChild.parent = rotRoot
    newRoot.parent = rotRoot.parent
    if rotRoot.isRoot():
        self.root = newRoot
    else:
        if rotRoot.isRightChild():
            rotRoot.parent.rightChild = newRoot
        else:
            rotRoot.parent.leftChild = newRoot
    newRoot.rightChild = rotRoot
    rotRoot.parent = newRoot
    rotRoot.balanceFactor = rotRoot.balanceFactor + 1 \
        - min(newRoot.balanceFactor, 0)
    newRoot.balanceFactor = newRoot.balanceFactor + 1 \
        + max(rotRoot.balanceFactor, 0)

def rotateLeft(self, rotRoot):
    newRoot = rotRoot.rightChild
    if newRoot.leftChild:
        rotRoot.rightChild = newRoot.leftChild
    if newRoot.leftChild != None:
        newRoot.leftChild.parent = rotRoot
    newRoot.parent = rotRoot.parent
    if rotRoot.isRoot():
        self.root = newRoot
    else:
        if rotRoot.isLeftChild():
            rotRoot.parent.leftChild = newRoot
        else:
            rotRoot.parent.rightChild = newRoot
    newRoot.leftChild = rotRoot
    rotRoot.parent = newRoot
    rotRoot.balanceFactor = rotRoot.balanceFactor + 1 \
        - min(newRoot.balanceFactor, 0)
    newRoot.balanceFactor = newRoot.balanceFactor + 1 \
        + max(rotRoot.balanceFactor, 0)
```

Comment: Well, the balance factor is set to 0 for every new node created. But later on in the code, when I'm properly placing that node to its place in order to keep the tree as balanced, I am updating the balance factor as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about improving working code, it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com it is off-topic here.